# ¿Hay manera tener un listener para cuando aparece un dialogo en el navegador web?

Tags: javascript, html

Sucede que consulto un servicio que por respuesta me entrega la descargar un archivo.

La manera en que consulto el servicio es:

```
function callDownload() {
        var form = document.getElementById('valores');
        form.action = 'getFilter';
        form.method = 'POST';
        validNavigation = true;
        form.submit();
        mascara();
    }
```

Todo debe ser en la misma vista y no puedo recargar la pagina, entonces pasa que cuando mando a llamar el servicio, muestro un modal de espera ... cuando ya me responde el servicio y se visualiza el dialogo de la descarga. 
[image: descarga]
Pero el modal de espera continua mostrandose y no debe ser asi.

La solucion que se me ocurre es poner un listener que se accione cuando aparezca el dialogo de descarga, y de esa manera ocultar el modal de espera, pero hasta ahora no he encontrado con javascript el evento para poder cachar tal accion.

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que devuelve la llamada al servidor? ¿Sólo es un *submit* del *form*...?

Comment: ```response.setContentType("application/xls");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Historico_" + date + ".xls");
    response.setContentLength((int) archivoXLS.length());```

Comment: eso es lo que mando desde el servidor ... y si solo es un submit